# Read multiple csv files with Pandas assign different names

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

How do I read different csv files in folder without concatenating them but just assigning them with the original file name? For example, file with path ...\table1.csv will be named "table1"

I managed to get all file names how do I read each file now?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath= ...
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

In other words, instead of reading multiple csv files in pandas like this:

```
table1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Folder\Desktop\FolderA\FolderB\Sub_Folder\OneDrive_1_22-06-2022\table1.csv')

table2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Folder\Desktop\FolderA\FolderB\Sub_Folder\OneDrive_1_22-06-2022\table2.csv')

table3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Folder\Desktop\FolderA\FolderB\Sub_Folder\OneDrive_1_22-06-2022\table3.csv')
...
```

is there a better way?

Comment: can you use a dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How loop and store values in independent variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671109/how-loop-and-store-values-in-independent-variable-in-python)

Comment: I don't think declaring variables from external inputs is a good practice, sure you can do it with eval or exec. But this makes the program unpredictable and vulnerable, for almost most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pathlib` and dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

dfs = {f.stem: pd.read_csv(f) for f in pathlib.Path().glob('*.csv')}
```

**Strongly discouraged, prefer method above**

If you want to create variables dynamically:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    locals()[name] = df
    # locals()[f"df_{name}"] = df
```

Output:

```
>>> data1
   0:00  0:30
0     1     5
1     2     6
2     3     7
3     4     8
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thanks for your solution, instead of getting data in a whole chunk, can I assign them with different names and pandas dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean? Is it not already the case here: one file, one variable?

Comment: It's working now! Sorry I missed out the second bit - may I know it's discouraged?

Comment: For example, your file names need to be valid python identifier. `data 1.csv` is not a valid python identifier. If you search files recursively, you can have 2 files with same name and override a variable previously defined (but this is the same problem for a dict :))

Comment: May I ask what `f.stem: pd.read_csv(f)` does?

Comment: @WeiShanLee. `f` is an instance of `Path` class, so [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) is the filename without its extension.

Comment: @Corralien Shouldn't we write `pd.read_csv(f.stem)` instead of the original `f.stem: pd.read_csv(f)` ?

Comment: No if you do this, you remove the extension: `pd.read_csv(f.stem)` will fail with an exception "FileNotFound" because you try to read a file named "data" instead of "data.csv".

Answer (score 1):

```
dfs = {file.split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(file) for file in onlyfiles}
print(dfs['table1'])
...
<Your dataframe here>
```

Answer (score 1):

let's try:

```
for file in onlyfiles:
    # get file name
    fname = file.split('.')[0]

    # read dataframe with file name as variable name
    exec('{} = pd.read_csv(file)'.format(fname))
```